Context-Free Grammar for the Complement of $L=\{a^ib^jc^k|j>i+k+2\}$
I am trying to get the CFG of the complement of the below:
$L = \{ a^i b^j c^k | j > i + k + 2 \}$
I have been struggling with this for hours now.
I have already constructed part of the CFG for ( L' ), which accounts for strings which are out of order. I think I should construct this L' by doing S -> S1 | S2 where S1 is the out of order and S2 is the in order but the complement of the condition "j > i + k + 2"
Start Symbol: ( S )
\begin{aligned}
S1 &\to X \mid Y \mid Z \\
X &\to A ba A \\
Y &\to A ca A \\
Z &\to A cb A \\
A &\to a A \mid b A \mid c A \mid \epsilon
\end{aligned}
Accepted:
abca
cab
not accepted:
b
a
c
abc
ab
I can't however for the life of me get the second part where the order is correct but the complement of the condition is taken into account
Complement of the original condition should be: "j <= i + k + 2"
What is the CFG of this part?
